# Lower central series of nearly metabelian groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let's say that $G \in \mathcal M_k$ if every $k$-generated subgroup of $G$ is metabelian. Obviously, $\mathcal M_{\geq 4} = \mathcal M_4 = \mathcal M$ is the variety of metabelian groups, but it's known that $\mathcal M \subsetneq \mathcal M_3 \subsetneq \mathcal M_2$. It's pretty easy to see that $\mathcal M_2$ is generated by single word $[[a, b], [a^{-1}, b]]$.

Associated lower central quotients of free metabelian groups are known to be free abelian of polynomial growth (exactly, for rank $r$ $n$-th lower central quotient has dimension $(n-1) {r+n-2 \choose n}$).

**Question 1**. Are there any results about lower central quotients of free groups in varieties $\mathcal M_k$, at least rationally?

**Question 2**. How well IA-automorphisms of free $\mathcal M_k$-groups lift to free groups? More generally, automorphisms inducing identity on $\gamma_k$?

Comment: Rationally, if I'm correct the first question converts into a problem of Lie algebras: it seems to amount to understanding the variety of Lie algebras (over $\mathbf{Q}$) in which any 2 / any 3 elements generate a metabelian subalgebra, and nilpotent of some given step.

Comment: Why do you want to study ${\mathcal M}_2$, and why is it given by one identity $[[a,b], [a^{-1},b]]$? It might be that the free groups in this variety are not residually nilpotent.

Comment: Hanna Neumann's book says $\mathcal M_3$ is given by $[[x,y][x,z]]$ if it of note.

Comment: @MarkSapir No particular reason, just trying to get familiar with automorphisms of free and free metabelian groups. Also I just like to see what happens in two varieties when first few free groups in them are very similar (or just isomorphic) — do they behave similarly furher, and nilpotent residual properties are first things I look at.

Comment: So I've asked this question because it might be already known.

Comment: The groups in ${\mathcal M}_2$ may be quite nasty (I am not sure but why not?). It is a little misleading calling these groups "nearly metabelian"). It is quite possible that the variety contains an infinite finitely generated simple (or torsion) group. I do not think anybody studied this variety.

Comment: @DenisT. can you please give me a reference to a source of the statement ""associated lower central quotients of free metabelian groups are known to be free abelian of poly. growth"? I'm interested in reading about groups that have the same lower central series.

Comment: @Mariah Reference is K. T. Chen, Integration in free groups, 1951. But there's an wasy way to obtain it via pure group theory + commutative algebra. Commutant of free metabelian group is a module over abeliabization, i.e. module over Laurent polynomial ring. Now there's obvious basis of commutant as freee abelian group $\{ x_1^{n_1}\cdots x_m^{n_m} x_l (x_1^{n_1}\cdots x_l^{n_l+1} \cdots x_m^{n_m})^{-1} \mid n_i \in \mathbb{Z}, 1 \le l < m \le k, n_m \ne 0\}$, and adic filtration is same as lower central which is easy to see.